# Android TextView XML property to format the input text

Tags: android

I am populating a ListView using TextView as a row through SimpleCursorAdapter.The numbers in the TextView are displayed as say 8 or 2.6786 etc.I want them to be displayed as 8.00 or 2.67 etc.Can it be done through XML(like input Type method etc).Please suggest a wayout. The codes are:

```
// THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
columns = new String[] { slStock.KEY_SCRIPT,  getColumnName(2),c.getColumnName(3)};
// THE XML DEFINED VIEWS FOR EACH FIELD TO BE BOUND TO
to = new int[] { R.id.tvstockscrpt, R.id.tvqty ,R.id.tvstockrate};
// CREATE ADAPTER WITH CURSOR POINTING TO DESIRED DATA

SimpleCursorAdapter cursAdapter = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rowstock,   c,columns, to); 

lvstockdisplay.setAdapter(cursAdapter);
```

Here you will notice that the cursor c fetches data (from database sql query in background) and populates it in the ListView directly.The question is how can I format the cursor data for say the TextView whose id is(R.id.tvstockrate) and which is populated by c.getColumnNames(3).At which point in the codes the format statement can be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can format the numbers via XML, but the following should work to format to 2 decimal places:

```
DecimalFormat numbers = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

You should be able to adapt this as required by your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can not round up the value from your xml, so you have to do programmatically after getting you value in cursor and get it into double and use the below code.

Try out as below :

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html